# transfer file to remote host and append to file if existing

Tags: curl, file-transfer

I have a command-line program that continuously generates output on the shell.

I would like to be able to transfer the output to another unix host for which I know IP, username and password.

Since the program does not terminate, I would also like to continuously update the file, without removing the previous output.

Is there a way to do it from command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an ideal method would involve sending it to the remote server via syslog. This simple ssh command should also work:

```
somecommand | ssh somehost 'cat - >> file.log'
```

Comment: Be sure to set up key-pair authentication, so as not to have to bother with manually keying in a password every time you do this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Re-direct the command line program's output to a file with >> filename
2. Use rsync to send it onto the remote machine and file

Answer (score 0):

## Automation :

1.Install or compile *sshpass*
2.Add the lines to your `.bashrc`of `.profile`

```
HOSTNET=<YOUR_REMOT_HOST>
LOGINNET=<YOUR_REMOTE_LOGIN>
PASSNET=<YOUR_REMOTE_PASSWD>
teenet () {
    sshpass -p$PASSNET ssh $LOGINNET@$HOSTNET 'tee >> YOUR_REMOTE_LOG_FILE'
}
```

3.Now update your environment : `. ~/.bashrc`
You can now pipe every output to teenet.
**Example :**

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | teenet
```